# Numbering and titling graphs in R-markdown

Tags: pdf, plot, graphics, r-markdown

In r-markdown pdf report I need to number and caption all my graphs and nothing I could find on the internet helped. So each picture or graph displayed needs to be something like
"Picture 1: qq-plot of the variable "age"."
The problem is also with two graphs in a single code chunk. To be precise, they aren't in a single merged graph, but two separate graphs with each their own cooedinate system.

Comment: Can you add relevant code with your question so that it's more clear what you are trying to do?